# Form Not Posting To SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, dbconnection

I have this form and I can’t get it to post to my sql database?

https://xcanberracars.com/assets/booking/bookride_bu240118.php

This is the code I believe I have everything right but obviously not.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~(E_STRICT|E_NOTICE|E_WARNING));

$host="localhost";
$dbuser="xcanberr_accountmanager";
$dbpass="*********”;
$dbname="xcanberr_PromoCodes";

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);
if(!$link)
{
    echo "ERROR| Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;

    $booking_id = "XBR".date("dmYHis");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO booking_table (bookingID, first_name, last_name, email, phone, pickup_location, drop_location)
    VALUES ('$bookingId', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$email', '$phone,'$pickupAddressLine1', '$dropAddressLine1')";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

I can get it to work on my local host pc but won’t work on the server

Comment: It's probably not wise to publish the username and password for the database.

Comment: You should get the same SQL syntax error (if you were checking) on both servers, if the script was identical. Also a problem you wouldn't have with parameter binding, of course.

Comment: `$booking_id` is not the same as `'$bookingId',` check it out

Comment: Even if you don't care about security, your vulnerability to SQL injection is going to cause problems if someone called "O'Connor" wants to book something with you, as the apostrophe in their name will crash your code.

Answer (score 3):

In your code their is 2 mistakes.

1- line no. 19 '$phone should be '$phone'

2- line no. 21 mysqli_query($conn, $sql); should be  mysqli_query($link, $sql);

3- booking_id AND bookingId

use this code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~(E_STRICT|E_NOTICE|E_WARNING));

$host="localhost";
$dbuser="xcanberr_accountmanager";
$dbpass="*********”;
$dbname="xcanberr_PromoCodes";

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);
if(!$link){


    $bookingId = "XBR".date("dmYHis");

    $firstName          = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $firstName);
    $email              = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);
    $phone              = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $phone);
    $pickupAddressLine1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $pickupAddressLine1);
    $dropAddressLine1   = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $dropAddressLine1);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO booking_table (bookingID, first_name, last_name, email, phone, pickup_location, drop_location)
    VALUES ('$bookingId', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$email', '$phone','$pickupAddressLine1', '$dropAddressLine1')";

    mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

Comment: `$dbpass="*********”` < you missed that. Look at syntax highlighting here and in the OP's post.